# java.rmi.UnexpectedException: Failed to parse descriptor file; nested exception is: java.rmi.server.ExportException:

Tags: java, rmi

I have upgraded my web application from java6 to java7. I have deployed web tier, ejb tier and web service tier on weblogic 10.3 successfully. Everything works fine except stateful ejb. During these ejb invocation , I get following exception on server logs.

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: cannot unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnexpectedException: Failed to parse descriptor file; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.server.ExportException: Failed to export class SearchAccountSessionBean_qa86w0_EOImpl problem with rmi descriptor signature getFilterCount([Lcom.abc.SearchResultFilterName;)RemoteMethodSet=[setPrimaryKey(Ljava.lang.Object;), ......
```

Can anyone advice what may be the root cause. my ejb version is 2.0.

Comment: Yes, there is a "fail[ure] to export class `SearchAccountSessionBean_qa86w0_EOImpl` problem with rmi descriptor signature `getFilterCount([Lcom.abc.SearchResultFilterName;)RemoteMethodSet=[setPrimaryKey(Ljava.lang.Object;), ......`". If you post some details of that class you might get even more help.

Comment: Hi EJP, I found the issue with SearchResultFilterName class which was defineds as varargs datatype and giving issue. I changed to array and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the EJBCompilerCache in weblogic will have the old bean details resulting in the above said error.
Just clean the weblogic application server tmp and cache folders and try again.