# Weblogic Exception after deploy: java.rmi.UnexpectedException

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

Just encountered a similar issue as described in the below article:

[Question: Article with similar error description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323074/java-rmi-unexpectedexception-failed-to-parse-descriptor-file-nested-exception)

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: cannot unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnexpectedException: Failed to parse descriptor file; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Failed to export class
```

I found that the issue described is totally unrelated to any Java update and is rather an issue with the Weblogic bean-cache. It seems to use old compiled versions of classes when updating a deployment. I was hunting a similar issue in a related question ([Question: Interface-Implementation-mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174118/weblogic-how-to-prevent-a-mismatch-exists-between-the-bean-code-and-generated)).

How can I fix this properly to allow proper automatic deployment (with WLST)?

Answer (score 0):

After some feedback from the Oracle community it now works like this:

1) Shutdown the remote Managed Server

2) Delete directory "domains/#MyDomain#/servers/#MyManagedServer#/cache/EJBCompilerCache"

3) Redeploy EAR/application

In WLST (which one would need to automate this) this is quite tricky:

```
      import shutil

      servers=cmo.getServers()
      domainPath = get('RootDirectory')
      for thisServer in servers:
        pathToManagedServer = domainPath + "\\servers\\" + thisServer.getName()
        print ">Found managed server:" + pathToManagedServer
        pathToCacheDir = pathToManagedServer + "\\" + "cache\\EJBCompilerCache"
        if(os.path.exists(pathToCacheDir) and os.path.isdir(pathToCacheDir) ):
          print ">Found a cache directory that will be deleted:" + pathToCacheDir
          # shutil.rmtree(pathToCacheDir)
```

Note: Be careful when testing this, the path that is returned by "pathToCacheDir" depends on the MBean-context that is currently set. See samples for WLST command "cd()". You should first test the path output with "print domainPath" and later add the "rmtree" python command! (I uncommented the delete command in my sample, so that nobody accidentially deletes an entire domain!)